# regex in python, findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

im trying to find a specific string in a xml file.
this is my code so far:

```
data = re.findall(r'<tabular>(.*?)</tabular>' ,file)
```

so from the following xml file:

```
some stuff
    <tabular>
        mydata
    </tabular>
some stuff
```

i wish to extrackt mydata, but my code doesent seem to work.

Comment: Is this an XML data you are parsing?

Comment: Parsing xml with regex is a really bad idea

Answer (score 3):

Use `html or xml parsers` though here's a quickfix

```
data = re.findall(r'<tabular>([\s\S]*?)</tabular>' ,file)
```

`.` by default does not match `\n`.So either use `DOTALL` flag or `[\s\S]`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is here:

```
>>> data = re.findall(r"<tabular>([^<]+)<\/tabular>", file)
```